# Convert non-standard mm:ss to hh:mm:ss with T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am doing some data clean up from an old, text-based system.  The system tracks running time of films with a format like this: `'86:08'`.

This means 1 hour 26 minutes and 8 seconds.

I am able to convert the first part like this:

```
declare @t varchar(10)
set @t = '86:08'

select @t as t, 
t2 = try_convert(time,format(dateadd(minute,cast(left(@t, 2) as int),0),'hh:mm','en-US'))
```

Result:

```
t       t2
86:08   01:26:00.0000000
```

How can I get the seconds as well, so the result would be `01:26:08:0000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could recover the 2 rightmost digits and convert to seconds instead of minutes.

Consider:

```
try_convert(
    time,
    format(
        dateadd(second,cast(left(@t, 2) as int)*60 + cast(right(@t, 2) as int), 0),
    'hh:mm:ss','en-US')
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a07978983b7d02533f055bd5eda54986)**:

```
declare @t varchar(10)
set @t = '86:08'

select
    @t as t, 
   t2 = try_convert(
    time,
    format(
        dateadd(second,cast(left(@t, 2) as int)*60 + cast(right(@t, 2) as int), 0),
    'hh:mm:ss','en-US')
)

GO
```

```
t     | t2      
:---- | :-------
86:08 | 01:26:08
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

You need to multiply out to milliseconds as the fractional part is discarded.

```
SELECT DATEADD(ms, 86.08 * 1000, 0)
```

If you want it without the date portion you can use CONVERT, with style 114

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, 86.08 * 1000, 0), 114)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the value to seconds and back to a `time`:

```
select @t as t, 
       convert(time, dateadd(second, left(@t, 2) * 60 + right(@t, 2), 0))
```